# fragment's onCreatView gets called but not refreshing views, why?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to add some data to my view on a **fragment's onCreateView func.**
Strange thing, if i generate each time random ids, the logcat nicely shows, that all of them are different, but in **my EditText is only shows the very first of it at each and every run.**

Code:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String randomId = new Random().nextInt(10000) + "";

    Log.i("onCreateView()", randomId);
    testEdit.setText(randomId);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Log:

```
07-14 12:30:10.369: I/onCreateView()(4622): 6163
07-14 12:30:36.234: I/onCreateView()(4622): 5706
07-14 12:30:38.516: I/onCreateView()(4622): 2258
07-14 12:30:41.930: I/onCreateView()(4622): 4761
```

So when i firstly navigated to my fragment, **my EditText showed 6163.** 
After that i navigated to another fragment, then went back again to the problematic one.
The **new random id was 5706**, as logcat's second line shows, but **my EditText still showed 6163.**

No matter how many times i repeat this, the EditText only shows the very first value and never refreshing.

Why???

OnCreateView surely gets called, my randomIds surely different, still my view now refreshing. Why?

I use this replace functions to my fragments, maybe this is wrongly implemented:

```
    public void replace(Fragment fragmentToChange) {

    fragmentTransaction = act.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(container.getId(), fragmentToChange, fragmentToChange.getClass().getSimpleName());
    if (getCurrentFragment() != null && getCurrentFragment() != fragmentToChange) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentToChange.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

---

### **E D I T:**

### Very interesting fact: When i do the same with a TextView's text, it does the trick and working. Looks like EditText is bugged...?

Comment: Why aren't you inflating your fragments layout in onCreateView() and returning it? Instead you are returning super.onCreateView()?

Comment: I inflate using a public function, beacause i only inflate once.

Comment: How about wrapping setText() with runOnUithread?

Comment: @Adam Varhegyi How about wrapping setText() with runOnUithread?

Comment: I made a workaround: each time onCreateView is called, i make a new instance of an EditText, with new EitText(context), and that way it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
String randomId = new Random().nextInt(10000) + "";

testEdit = view.findViewById(R.id.testEdit);
Log.i("onCreateView()", randomId);
testEdit.setText(randomId);
return view;
```

Comment: how are you initializing testEdit?

Comment: Just as you advised. Each time on onCreateView.

Answer (score 0):

onCreateView(...) called to have the fragment instantiate its user interface view. This is optional, and non-graphical fragments can return null (which is the default implementation). This will be called between onCreate(Bundle) and onActivityCreated(Bundle).

If you return a View from here, you will later be called in onDestroyView() when the view is being released.

The system calls this method when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time.

Try this

```
              DiplayFragment newFragment = new DiplayFragment();

              FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                            .beginTransaction();
              transaction.replace(R.id.nav_fl_frag_container, newFragment);
              transaction.addToBackStack(null);
              transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I dont understand from this description why my EditText's text beheaving like unchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the fragment like this

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Article()).commit();
```

where Article is a Fragment and container is an id of FrameLayout